# How to create local task links for referenced entities on a node?

Tags: 8, routes

I have a content type, which has three reference fields to three different content types. I want to create secondary task links to those referenced entities.

Let's say that I have a **Product** content type which reference fields to **Manufacturer**, **Distributor** and **Technical Details** content types.

If you visit a content of type Product, I want to show three secondary tabs to Manufacturer, Distributor and Technical Details contents which are referenced from that specific node (Product).

Fore example, we have a product with following fields:

**Product X** (`node/1`):

- Manufacturer A (reference to node id: 2)
- Distributor B (reference to node id: 3)
- Technical Details X (reference to node id: 4)

If I visit Product X (`node/1`), I want to get three tabs to `node/2`, `node/3`, and `node/4`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Hudri On my case I want to create tabs linked to the referenced nodes. My question is not how to add tabs, it is specifically how to created tabs for the referenced nodes on a node view page.

Comment: In that case take a look at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/273062/dynamic-local-tasks-caching-problems

Comment: @leymannx no. My question is, how to create tabs to the referenced nodes. The both questions have nothing related to my issue.