# Set no cache when generating dynamic local action via derivatives

Tags: 9

I'm trying to generate a dynamic local action via a derivative. The derivative works and returns a link generated dynamically but the cache seems to maintain its value.

As per this [Drupal core change log](https://www.drupal.org/node/3013690), I understood I could set cache parameters on the derivative, which I tried but in vain so far - I'm not very familiar with these concepts yet so appreciate any guidance on how to prevent `$gid` from being cached.

Here's my local action `leads.links.action.yml`:

```
leads.new_deal:
  deriver: 'Drupal\leads\Plugin\Derivative\DynamicLocalTasks'
```

Here's my derivative:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\leads\Plugin\Derivative;

use Drupal\Component\Plugin\Derivative\DeriverBase;
use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableDependencyInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableDependencyTrait;


/**
* Defines dynamic local tasks.
*/
class DynamicLocalTasks extends DeriverBase {
  use CacheableDependencyTrait;
  /**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */
  public function getDerivativeDefinitions($base_plugin_definition) {
    $groupLead = getGroupsUserIsLead();

    if (isset($groupLead[0])){
      $gid = $groupLead[0];
    }
    else{
      return \Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult::forbidden();
    }

    // Implement dynamic logic to provide values for the same keys as in example.links.task.yml.
    $this->derivatives['leads.new_deal'] = $base_plugin_definition;
    $this->derivatives['leads.new_deal']['title'] = "New Deal";
    $this->derivatives['leads.new_deal']['route_name'] = 'entity.group_content.create_form';
    $this->derivatives['leads.new_deal']['appears_on'] = ['leads.deals'];
    $this->derivatives['leads.new_deal']['route_parameters'] = ['plugin_id' => 'group_node:deals','group' => $gid];
    $this->cacheMaxAge = 0;
    $this->getCacheMaxAge();
    
    return parent::getDerivativeDefinitions($base_plugin_definition);
  }

  public function getCacheMaxAge() {
    return 0;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the CacheableDependencyTrait to a deriver doesn't make it fully cacheable. There is no code in Drupal checking for cacheable dependencies of derivers in a normal request. You have to return the title, route name and so on from a local task plugin where you can also use getCache*() methods. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/273293/47547

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @4uk4, here's what I ended up doing:

```
leads.new_deal:
  route_name: entity.group_content.create_form
  title: 'New Deal'
  route_parameters:
    plugin_id: group_node:deals
    group: 0
  class: 'Drupal\leads\Plugin\Menu\DynamicLocalTasks'
  appears_on:
    - 'leads.deals'
```

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\leads\Plugin\Menu;

use Drupal\Core\Menu\LocalActionDefault;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;

class DynamicLocalTasks extends LocalActionDefault {
  public function getRouteParameters(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    $groupLead = getGroupsUserIsLead();

    $gid = $groupLead[0] ?? NULL;

    return [
      'plugin_id' => 'group_node:deals',
      'group' => $gid,
    ]; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that I didn't need to change the cache behavior with this method.