# Dynamic language links from menu?

Tags: i18n-l10n, navigation, 9

I am trying to find a way to do the following:

- Add languages to Drupal 9 menu items
- Translate content/menu links
- Provide (from the Main Navigation) a list of languages *the current page is translated in*

I was able to complete the first two, but I cannot see how to get a menu to list links that output the available language options for the current entity. I see that there is a Language Switcher block from core, but is there a way to make this appear baked into a Drupal menu itself?

[image]

Comment: I don't think this has been fully solved in core yet, there are modules to help like https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block_current_language, https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_manipulator, https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_multilingual

Comment: Hmmm... there must be a way to mimic this. I'll take a look around

Comment: For a code solution you would need a dynamic menu link plugin pointing at the current node derived for each language. Like this example for local tasks https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/292739/how-to-get-links-of-translated-node-edit-page-in-the-secondary-tabs

Comment: I see - that would work even if its not a local task? Like how would you get it appended to "Main Navigation"?

Answer (score 0):

You put the static infos in *.links.menu.yml where you also define dynamic menu link plugins, which provide the infos you can't put in a static yml. And the deriver to produce a plugin for each language. The local task example was just an example for the translation stuff.

A working static example:

*mymodule.links.menu.yml*

```
mymodule.language.top:
  title: 'EN'
  menu_name: main
  route_name: '<none>'
  expanded: true
  # Plugin class to override the title dynamically:
  # class: Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\Menu\TranslatedNodeTop
mymodule.language.item:
  title: 'Node 8 spanish'
  parent: mymodule.language.top
  route_name: entity.node.canonical
  route_parameters: { node: '8' }
  menu_name: main
  options:
    attributes:
      class:
        - foo-class
        - bar-class
  # deriver for installed languages
  deriver: Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\Derivative\TranslatedNodeTabDeriver
  # Plugin class extending MenuLinkDefault overriding static properties dynamically,
  # the route parameter from the current route match, the language from the deriver
  # the title from both and link attributes added for the current language:
  # class: Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\Menu\TranslatedNodeItem
```

You need to add the two dynamic plugins extending MenuLinkDefault. I've recycled the TranslatedNodeTabDeriver from [How to get links of translated node edit page in the secondary tabs](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/292739/how-to-get-links-of-translated-node-edit-page-in-the-secondary-tabs).